# How to compare current excel cell to previous excel cell in same column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a quick function to compare the current cell in a column to the cell just above (before) it. The idea is to perform a different operation on data that is in the same column but different value.

```
if (df.loc() != df.loc[::-1] & df1.loc() != df1.loc[:-1]):
df = df.iloc()
df1 = df1.iloc()
```

My thinking was to compare the current location to the current location -1, and if they are the same then to proceed. Otherwise do another task when the cell value changes. I am doing this to two different data frames that have the same column name in each that I am trying to read through.

```
   Connector  Pin        Adj.  
0       F123    1       2 6 7  
1       F123    2   1 3 6 7 8  
2       F123    3   2 4 7 8 9  
3       F123    4  3 5 8 9 10  
4       F123    5      4 9 10  
5       F123    6       1 2 7  
6       F123    7   1 2 3 6 8  
7       F123    8   2 3 4 7 9  
8       F123    9  3 4 5 8 10  
9       F123   10       4 5 9  
10      C137    1         2 1  
11      C137    2         1
```

After iterating down this table, when the Connector changes from F123 to C137 I want to clear all columns above the first C137.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the below dataframe:

```
print(df)

 Connector  Pin        Adj.
0       F123    1       2 6 7
1       F123    2   1 3 6 7 8
2       F123    3   2 4 7 8 9
3       F123    4  3 5 8 9 10
4       F123    5      4 9 10
5       F123    6       1 2 7
6       F123    7   1 2 3 6 8
7       F123    8   2 3 4 7 9
8       F123    9  3 4 5 8 10
9       F123   10       4 5 9
10      C137    1         2 1
11      C137    2           1
```

If you use:

```
df.drop(range(df.Connector.ne(df.Connector.shift()).cumsum().idxmax()))

   Connector  Pin Adj.
10      C137    1  2 1
11      C137    2    1
```

This will identify the change and drop those rows before where the change in connector has happen

Comment: My issue is that I am trying to do this with strings and not integers, so I don't thing diff() is going to work.

Comment: Can you post a sample v/s expected? please to test

Comment: I updated the post with a picture of what I am working with and a little more about what I am trying to do.

Comment: @MaxB i didnt understand that, please post a sample data and a expected output in code format (not image)

Comment: Ok edited to try and explain better. I don't really have an expected output right now I am simply trying to manipulate the table.

Comment: It doesn't seem to alter the table when inserted into the program.

Comment: I dont undetstand what you mean by " I want to clear all columns above the first C137."

Comment: Any time my program reaches a new connector I want all data relating to previous connectors to be removed from the table.

Comment: No matter where it is inserted into the code it doesn't seem to affect it. Might be an error on my end.

Comment: Hmm. Don't know until i see the complete data and expected output

Comment: Also hope you are reassigning the last line of the code back to df. Else the original df won't get modified. `df=df.drop... `

Comment: That fixed the issue but now I can't figure out how to print the data I have been working on before dropping it so now it only does the calculations on the bottom two rows, I will figure that out. Thank you for the help.